# How to define a tree data structure that has edge type

Tags: scala, types, functional-programming

I want to define a tree datastructure that has a label for its edges, here is my initial thought:

```
sealed trait Tree[+N,+E]
case class Branch[N,E](value:N, children:Map[E, Tree[N,E]]) extends Tree[N,E]
case class Leaf[N](value:N) extends Tree[N, Unit]
```

As you may guess, if I make a tree instance like following, the type of the instance would be `Tree[Int, Any]`. I also don't want to have a contravariant type for `E`.

```
  val tree =
    Branch(0,
      Map(
        "a" -> Leaf(1),
        "b" -> Branch(2,
          Map(
            "c" -> Leaf(4))))
    )
```

I want to know what would be a better way to implement this Tre. I've heard of Fix type classes and recursion schemes but I don't know if they can be useful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have `Leaf` extend `Tree[N, Nothing]`, not `Tree[N, Unit]`. `Nothing` is a bottom type, so that means `Leaf[N]` will be a subtype of `Tree[N, E]` for any `E` since you have it covariant.

```
case class Leaf[N](value:N) extends Tree[N, Nothing]
```

With that change, your example tree definition works just fine.

Fixpoint types are more complicated but not always necessary. But you could certainly modify this to make use of them. If you do want to go down that road, it might be better to ask it as another more specific question.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to put extend and if I extend the Leaf with Nothing, it works fine and I was careless!